# Logic for an init function in email parser

Tags: python, parsing, constructor, email

I am writing an email parser and cannot decide how much logic should be included in the `__init__` function. I know that a constructor should make the object ready for use, but are there best practices?

I've added several statements to my constructor:

```
def __init__(self, message):
    assert isinstance(message, basestring)

    parsed_message = email.message_from_string(message)

    if self._is_email(parsed_message):
        self.email_obj = parsed_message  
        email_payload = parsed_message.get_payload()
        self.valid_urls = self._find_valid_urls(email_payload)
        # ... some other stuff like looking for keywords etc.
```

What do you consider the most pythonic way:

- Should I create a simple email object which possesses several methods that extract and return keywords, included URLs etc?
- Do you consider it better to process all this information in the `__init__` method and putting all results in object variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, I think you should do something like

```
@classmethod
def parse(cls, message):    
    parsed_message = email.message_from_string(message)

    cls._verify_email(parsed_message) # throws if something is wrong

    message = cls() # make an e-mail message object 
    email_payload = parsed_message.get_payload()
    message.valid_urls = self._find_valid_urls(email_payload)
    # ... some other stuff like looking for keywords etc.

    return message
```

Which you would then use like

```
 my_message = Message.parse(message_text)
```

I prefer to leave the constructor for just basic object construction. It shouldn't parse things or do complex logic. It gives you flexibility because it is now possible to construct an e-mail object that isn't just a parsed version of the message text. I often find that useful for testing, and it reduces the dependance on a particular source for e-mails.

Answer (score 4):

Notes:

- Personally I prefer to keep the initialization method simple and lean. Just setup the minimum state of the object, let subsequent calls to methods do the real job when it's needed. Otherwise, why use a class? Maybe you don't need a class at all and just a function would do?
- `assert isinstance(message, basestring)`: Python is a dynamic language, embrace the fact and don't lose a second checking whether every argument has the type you expect (instead, write good docstrigs so the user knows how to call it). Another question is checking that given values satisfy some precondition (i.e `assert len(s) >= 10`).

Answer (score 1):

I think you should keep in mind these two principles in mind:

1. DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself)
2. SRP (Single Responsibility Principle)

According to SRP, your init function should be just initializing your object. All other stuff should go into their respective functions and called as needed.

```
email = Email(message)

if not email.is_valid: # Do some stuff

urls = email._valid_urls # use property here
```